# error C1075 when using Opencv_2.4.9 with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

After linking libraries from openpc 2.4.9 with visual studio 2010, I build and ran a program and got this error message.

`error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{'at ' c:\users\iggy\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\open_cv_test\open_cvtest\main.cpp(6)' was matched.`

---

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int main(){
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("C:\\Users\\9589693153\\Desktop\\Vids\\sqlite.png"); //change the name(image.jpg) according to your Image filename.

    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cvShowImage("Example1", img);

    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);

    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ybz0xh2.aspx) is usually caused by an unmatched bracket, brace, or other paired character.

For your case, remove the extra `}`:

```
int main(){
          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

#### please stop using the deprecated c-api, it's a dead end.

rather write code in c++, *please*.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main() //{ <-- here's your excessive {, like herohuyongtao pointed out before
{
    Mat img = imread("C:\\Users\\9589693153\\Desktop\\Vids\\sqlite.png"); //change the name(image.jpg) according to your Image filename.

    namedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    imshow("Example1", img);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```